# Processing javascript XMLHttpRequest on server in C

Tags: javascript, c, xml, http

I have javascript web page sending commands to a tiny web-server written in C. The server receives and processes the commands no problem, but when the server tries to send the response, it seems the web-page doesnt receive it.

Here is the javascript code

```
function httpGet(command)
{
    var theUrl="http://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + "/command?abcd=abcd&" + command;
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // need SYNCHRONOUS request
    xmlHttp.send( );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

The problem is that the javascript code never returns from the send() above.

Here is some of the server code in C:

```
ret =read(fd,buffer,BUFSIZE);

...code to parse out the command from the GET...
...code to process the command

//send the response
sprintf(buffer,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\nContent-Length: 0\nConnection: close\n\n");
write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
sleep(2); // sleep drains the socket
close(fd);
```

The C code runs to completion, but yet no response is received by the web browser, causing the javascript to hang in the send()

The server doesnt have any data to send back to it sends a content length of 0.

Is this the correct way to response to a javascript XMLHttpRequest()?

Thanks
rough

Comment: You don't need to `sleep()` to "drain a socket". It's not like copper plumbing :)

Comment: try `xmlHttp.send("")`. 

(as an aside, if you receive XML, you might want to use ``return xmlHttp.responseXML``)

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly sending sending carriage returns(\r) with you line feed(\n)

```
sprintf(buffer,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: I tried adding the \r\n just now, but still the server gets and processes the commands but the browser never gets the response. It doesnt even show that its getting any bytes when I use the browsers debugger

Comment: Make sure the buffer is big enough to hold the data.

Comment: yes the buffer is big enough, thanks for the comment. However, I used wireshark and the data is being sent to the browser, but still it never returns from the javascript send()

Comment: Try using async ajax, also you set a content type for xml but send nothing.

Comment: Its really a one way thing, there isnt anything to send back. I just tried sending something back because it was getting stuck on the send.

Comment: I dont know how to construct a response for ajax from a C program. Anyody knows?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, I needed to send one last \n, one more byte after the specified length in the return header.

Comment: @NS you should post an answer so anyone with a similar problem can find it as an answer.